# Jquery ajax submit data internal server error

Tags: jquery, asp.net, ajax

I'm getting the `internal server error:500` from `webservice`. Could you please help me to identify the cause?

```
$(document).ready(function () {
            $("#btnSubmit").click(InsertRegistration);
        });

        function InsertRegistration() {
            var Name = $("#Text1").val;
            var Designation = $("#Text2").val;
            var Address = $("#Text3").val;

            $.ajax(
                {
                    url: "Web/Employee.asmx/StoreEmployee",
                    type: "POST",
                    contenType: "application/json; charset=utf-8"",
                    dataType: "json",
                    data: "{'Name' : '" + Name + "','Designation':'" + Designation + "','Address':'" + Address + "'}",

                    success: function (result) {
                        var div = $("#divMessage");
                        div.InnerHtml = result.d;
                        div.html(result.d).fadeIn(1000);
                        setTimeout(function () { div.fadeOut(1000) }, 5000);

                    },
                    error: function (xhr, status) {
                        alert("An error occured " + status);
                    }

                }
            );
        }
```

My Web Service is as below i have added script service to the class and [ScriptMethod(ResponseFormat = ResponseFormat.Json)]

```
[ScriptService]
[WebService(Namespace = "http://tempuri.org/")]
[WebServiceBinding(ConformsTo = WsiProfiles.BasicProfile1_1)]
// To allow this Web Service to be called from script, using ASP.NET AJAX, uncomment the following line. 
// [System.Web.Script.Services.ScriptService]
public class Employee : System.Web.Services.WebService {

    SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(
            "Data Source=ADMN-PC;Initial Catalog=demoDb;Integrated Security=true");

    public Employee () {

        //Uncomment the following line if using designed components 
        //InitializeComponent(); 
    }
    string Name , Designation , Address;

    [WebMethod]
    [ScriptMethod(ResponseFormat = ResponseFormat.Json)]
    public string StoreEmployee(string Name, string Designation, string Address)
    {
        this.Name = Name;
        this.Designation = Designation;
        this.Address = Address;

        if (InsertEmployeeDB() > 0)
        {
            return "Saved Succesfully";
        }
        else
        {
            return "Error occured while saving...";
        }


    }
    public int InsertEmployeeDB()
    {
        try
        {

            SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("insert into  tblEmp_Personal (Name ,Designation,Address) values ('" + Name + "','" + Designation + "','" + Address + "')",conn);
            conn.Open();
            return cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
        }
        catch (SqlException ex)
        {

        }

        return 0;
    }

}
```

Comment: "500" Internal Server Error means, You've error in executing your server side script `Web/Employee.asmx/StoreEmployee` So it'll be better if you share that code too.

Comment: can you please edit and let me know vedant thanks i have tried with the Script method attribute also

Comment: use JSON.strinigify in your ajax on your data like this data: JSON.stringify({Name:Name,Address:Address}) .You can also add other varibles seperated by comma.

Comment: Can you post stack trace instead?

Answer (score 0):

Your data part in ajax will create an invalid json string. Change the `data` like this

```
data: JSON.stringify({
    Name: Name,
    Designation: Designation,
    Address: Address
}),
```

Then your ajax will look like this,

```
 $.ajax({
     url: "Web/Employee.asmx/StoreEmployee",
     type: "POST",
     contenType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
     dataType: "json",
     data: JSON.stringify({
         Name: Name,
         Designation: Designation,
         Address: Address
     }),

     success: function(result) {
         var div = $("#divMessage");
         div.InnerHtml = result.d;
         div.html(result.d).fadeIn(1000);
         setTimeout(function() {
             div.fadeOut(1000)
         }, 5000);

     },
     error: function(xhr, status) {
         alert("
             An error occured " + status);
     }

 });
```

Now i got your problem. At the top of the webservice code, there is a commented line like this,

```
// To allow this Web Service to be called from script, using ASP.NET AJAX, uncomment the following line. 
// [System.Web.Script.Services.ScriptService]
```

Uncomment the line `[System.Web.Script.Services.ScriptService]`

Comment: can you please provide me some more help without stringify method @anoop

Comment: @farukmahir try to remove the content type and then remove the stringify method

Comment: what is your email id anoop joshi

Comment: why email? Just try to uncomment the top code and use the stringify method. It will work

Comment: because i wanted you to give my pc to u as remote but i think u r over possisve like a gal @anoop

Comment: @farukmahir have you fixed the issue ?

Answer (score 0):

Replace your code with this (only the part i have changed)

```
url: "Web/Employee.asmx/StoreEmployee",
                type: "POST",
                contenType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                dataType: "json",
                data: "{'Name' : '" + Name + "','Designation':'" + Designation + "','Address':'" + Address + "'}",

                success: function (result) {
                    var div = $("#divMessage");
                    div.InnerHtml = result.d;
                    div.html(result.d).fadeIn(1000);
                    setTimeout(function () { div.fadeOut(1000) }, 5000);

                },
```

you had placed double quotes 2 times in content type at end .Try this.

Comment: @farukmahir have you checked my answer? Is it working ?